# SQL statement wrong syntax

Tags: c#, sql

I have some trouble with this SQL statement. I searched arround but cant find the awnser. So here is the statement I use to obtain the data of users that suit my condidtions:

```
SqlConnection connection = null;
try
{
    connection = new SqlConnection(Main.Settings.Connectionstring);
    connection.Open();
}
catch (Exception)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Failure at creating a connection to the database!", "Fehler", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    return;
}
if (tabPage == TabPageEnum.Email)
{
    SqlCommand importUser = new SqlCommand("select      address.ADR_FIRSTNAME, address.ADR_LASTNAME, address.ADR_EMAIL1, address.ADR_ID" +
                                            "from       dbo.ADDRESS as address, dbo.EMPLOYEE as emp" +
                                            "where      emp.EMP_ADR_ID = address.ADR_ID" +
                                            "and        address.GCRecord IS NULL" +
                                            "and        address.ADR_EMAIL1 IS NOT NULL" +
                                            "and        (address.ADR_FIRSTNAME IS NOT NULL" +
                                            "or         address.ADR_LASTNAME IS NOT NULL)", connection);
}
```

I appreciate any help!
If there is any other information needed so please tell me.

Comment: If you put the SQL into a variable and printed it out, the error would be obvious.  You should learn how to debug code.

Comment: You droped the spaces at the end of each line.

Comment: Itishardtoparsesqlwithoutspacesbetweenkeywords.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
address.ADR_ID" + "from
```

This result in: address.ADR_IDfrom

You should add spaces at the ends or beginnings of the different parts of your query.

Like this::

```
address.ADR_ID " + "from
```

Comment: thank you for your fast feedback, I feel so stupid about that

Comment: @Simon feeling stupid about your own code is the first step to get better since you dont want to repeat it and feel stupid once again

Answer (score 3):

Did you check the spaces. I think in every row of the command is missing a space

Answer (score 1):

The construct like

```
ADR_ID" + "from        dbo.ADDRESS as address, dbo.EMPLOYEE as emp
```

will give you

```
ADR_IDfrom       dbo.ADDRESS as address, dbo.EMPLOYEE as emp
```

where **ADR_IDfrom** is obviously not valid SQL. You need to put spaces at the end of each string where needed to form valid SQL.
Also consider putting your code into try block and check for exceptions. It might help you greatly. See [SqlError class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlerror(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Like the others mentioned the missing spaces are your problem.

An alternative way to write your query is to use an `@`-quoted string. Using this you don't have to escape any characters and can easily writ a multline string:

```
SqlCommand importUser = new SqlCommand(
        @"select   address.ADR_FIRSTNAME, address.ADR_LASTNAME, address.ADR_EMAIL1, address.ADR_ID
            from       dbo.ADDRESS as address, dbo.EMPLOYEE as emp
            where      emp.EMP_ADR_ID = address.ADR_ID
            and        address.GCRecord IS NULL
            and        address.ADR_EMAIL1 IS NOT NULL
            and        (address.ADR_FIRSTNAME IS NOT NULL
            or         address.ADR_LASTNAME IS NOT NULL)", connection);
```

Answer (score 1):

Heve you checked the space. ope it helps